# How to configure the login mechanism for SpringBoot in Swagger UI?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have an application written in Spring Boot. I use Swagger.
How to configure the swagger to show the user login mechanism?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: This is a basic configuration that only talks about saving. I want to be able to check the login to the account, not just save the user.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following configuration in application.properties

```
security.basic.path=/swagger-ui.html
security.basic.enabled=true
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=admin123
```